# Google API Images type text/html

Tags: api, google-api, mime-types, gif, google-image-search

I am using Google API for searching and retriving images. I observed that for some images chrome gives an warning saying 'Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html'. Those all were .gif images. But I also received other .gif images with no errors.

I read about text/html and found out that it is a server side issue and we need to configure the server. Now, since I cannot configure the Google server(or the servers Google fetched the data from), my doubts are,

1. Can i still display those images via some other way ?
2. Is this issue only with .gif's or other image types also
3. If yes, how can I exclude gif's from the search API

My Ajax URL

```
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?&v=1.0&q=' + query + '&rsz=8'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Actually, it was because the sites from where the images were coming from were blocked at my workplace. Hence the error.